# expected shortfall as unconditional expectation

Tags: backtesting, value-at-risk

Acerbi has several backtests for expected shortfall. The second backtest is based on this equality [image][image]

**Does anybody know how to derive this equality? Can anybody explain, why it makes sense, especially dividing by $\alpha$?**

---

Background:
I took the equality from this presentation https://www.cass.city.ac.uk/faculty-and-research/faculties/finance/seminars-and-workshops/financial-engineering-workshops/ACERBI-Carlo-10.03.2015.pdf

This is how I know expected shortfall

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $X_t$ be a random variable, its [conditional expectation with respect to some event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) $E$ is given by:

$$ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X_t|E]=\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbf{1}_EX_t]}{\mathbb{P}(E)}$$

In our case, Expected Shortfall is defined as:

$$ \text{ES}_{\alpha,t} = -\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X_t|X_t + \text{VaR}_{\alpha} < 0]$$

Hence:

$$ \begin{align}
\text{ES}_{\alpha,t} & = -\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_t + \text{VaR}_{\alpha} < 0\}}X_t]}{\mathbb{P}(X_t + \text{VaR}_{\alpha} < 0)} 
\\[9pt]
& = -\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_t + \text{VaR}_{\alpha} < 0\}}X_t]}{\alpha} 
\\[11pt]
& = -\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_t + \text{VaR}_{\alpha} < 0\}}X_t}{\alpha}\right] 
\end{align} $$

Where the second step is a consequence of the definition of $\text{VaR}_{\alpha}.$